# docusignapi - Failed to instantiate [com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient]

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, docusignapi

I have a Spring boot application and wanted to add docusign integration.

Starting from OauthCode/OauthToken to get the authcode and auth token.
I added the dependencies in gradle but docusign ApiClient instantiation is failing.

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.13.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}
                
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign'
    implementation 'com.docusign:docusign-esign-java:3.19.0'
    implementation 'jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:3.1.0'***
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.11'
    implementation 
               'io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager- 
                config:2.4.2'
              
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'

    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
                
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}
```

```java
@Generated
@Configuration
public class BeansConfig {
    @Value("${ds.api.base.path1}")
    private String basePath1;

    @Value("${ds.api.auth.base.path2}")
    private String basePath2;
            
    @Bean
    ApiClient getApiClient() {
        ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath1);
        apiClient.setOAuthBasePath(basePath2);
        return apiClient;
    }
}
```

Exception trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient]: Factory method 'apiClient' threw exception;
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/ext/ContextResolver at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) 
~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/ext/ContextResolver
```

Comment: Can you try 3.21.0 (for docusign-esign-java) and see if it fixes it?

Comment: Also, did you try to get the quickstart from here - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I tried quick start and saw it uses older jdk. Also tried with 3.21.0 didnt work. However 3.18.0 worked for me with jakarta.ws.rs-api:2.1.6. But I wanted to use latest published docusign sdk which doesnt work as of now

Comment: Yes sorry about that, we're working on this, but it will take some time. Can you use 3.18.0 for now?

Comment: yes, I am using 3.18.0 now. Once issue fixed, if I can get notice, will plan to upgrade

Comment: I will let you know by posting here, sorry about that. Also feel free to email me at inbar.gazit@docusign.com

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that was introduced in the latest version of the Java SDK. Version 3.18.0 doesn't have this bug, so for now the workaround is to use the oldest version.
I'll update this answer once we have released a new version that fixes this issue.

Comment: Hi, Is this issue got resolved. Which latest version can be used without error, please suggest ? My organization asked to upgrade to latest version for all libraries

Comment: 4.2.0 should support Jakarta now

Comment: (any version 4.x.x)

Comment: I am still getting same issue. Can you please help the dependencies versions of    implementation 'com.docusign:docusign-esign-java'
    implementation 'jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api' and implementation 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime' or any other dependencies

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I am using jdk 17

Comment: Yes, this is too old a version, we only support Java version 8 or later

Comment: Sorry, I mentioned We are using java 17 which is higher than version 8

Comment: "Can you please help the dependencies versions of implementation 'com.docusign:docusign-esign-java'" -  Can you clarify this question? Or provide more context? The Java ESign SDK 4.2.0 should be compatible with Java SDK 17 and Spring.

Comment: @InbarGazit facing here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78243005/failed-to-instantiate-com-docusign-esign-client-apiclient and not 4.2.0 not the latest RC doesn't solve the issues. any idea /?

Answer (score 0):

it's 12/2/2022 and I can confirm 3.21.0 still has this issue.  Downgrading to 3.18 works.

it would be **REALLY NICE** if the documentation published by docusign was updated to reflect this.  I lost an hour chasing my tail on this.

with 3.21.0 and boot 2.7.4 / java 11 the `ApiClient` instantiation fails with

```
ava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    at com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient.<init>(ApiClient.java:91) ~[docusign-esign-java-3.21.0.jar:na]
    at com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient.<init>(ApiClient.java:123) ~[docusign-esign-java-3.21.0.jar:na]
    at com.myapp.Application.auth(Application.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
```