# Failed to instantiate [com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, docusignapi

**TASK:**
Migration from Spring Boot 2.7.18 to 3.2 and Java 11 to Java 17 and had a dependency from `com.docusign.docusign-esign-java`

Used the last stable version

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.docusign</groupId>
    <artifactId>docusign-esign-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**ERRORS:**

```text
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient]: Factory method 'apiClient' threw exception with message: org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/BodyPart
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:644)
    ... 47 common frames omitted
```

Comment: If you solve your own question, please feel free to add a real answer for it (not inside the question but as an extra step) - don't add "[SOLVED]" to the title, SO handles this differently. You can then accept your own answer and the question will be marked as solved by SO means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

> Need to additionally the libs in your pom.xml if that is acceptatble for you: The [docusign 4.5.0](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-java-client/blob/4.5.0-v2.1-23.3.01.02/pom.xml) using [jerseay-version 3.0.9](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-java-client/blob/4.5.0-v2.1-23.3.01.02/pom.xml#L398) but the following dependencies not retrieved with docusign. The Spring Boot 3.2 had dependencies jersey libraries 3.1.5 built in.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
```